# Why do external Java libraries paths have to be refreshed in eclipse between starts?

Tags: eclipse, libraries

For my school projects, I use the joda-time API for generating timestamps that are used for file names and logging.

Getting eclipse to recognize the library is no problem.  However, when I start eclipse between reboots, I get the red X in the project tree because the external API cannot be found, even though the file path has not changed.  So each time, I have to go to the Libraries tab in Build Path to re-target the API.  Frankly, this is getting to be a PIMA.

So is there any way to have the path be permanent, so I don't have to do the Build Path rigmarole all the time?

Comment: Could you add more information of your setup? Just the following: Eclipse version, creation of what kind of project, how do you have the library included, ...? So we have a chance to reconstruct your problem.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse 3.4, and the projects are school projects for introductory algorithms.  I have the joda time library in a different folder than the Eclipse JARs, but have to link to it constantly.